# Snapping an Extrusion

Tags: extrude, snapping

Referring to the attached image, using a simple extrude and scale workflow, is it possible to snap the upper extrusion so it matches the size of the lower one? I thought this would be quite simple but I just can't seem to work it out....

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the top face deleted and vertices selected ...

- Set Pivot to *Median*
- Set snap to *Vertex* and *Active*, and set it to influence *Scale*. Check 'Project on to Self'.
- With cursor close to *Active* (white) vertex Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> Scale <kbd>S</kbd> Limited Axis <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and snap the active vertex to the one below it.

[image]

(Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging toggles the 'Snap' state.)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much ! That worked perfectly.